# How would one time out a thread if there is no input on System.in in the last 15 seconds

Tags: java, multithreading, timeout

I need to have thread listening to system.in, concatenating all input and, upon a certain command or if there is no input for 10 seconds it needs to run another thread that will use the collected information.
To be clear, Everytime data is inputed I need to reset the 10 seconds.
As a beginner to concurrent programming I'm not really sure how to approach this

Comment: You probably want to be looking at AsynchronousChannel, https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/channels/AsynchronousChannel.html.  However my Java isn't good enough to give you a definitive example! Also providing some example code showing what you've done so far will improve your chances of getting your question answered,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow!

A simple approach to achieve what you are asking is to [schedule](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#submit-java.util.concurrent.Callable-) a scanning command and wait for the corresponding [`Future`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) to return the result or throw an exception while waiting idle for an amount of time. By *scanning command* I mean a [`Callable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html) that will [scan the next line](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine--) from `System.in`.

In this case, you won't be needing to handle complex multithreading with handmade `Thread`s. Just create a suitable `ExecutorService` (by using the appropriate static method call from the [`Executors`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html) class) to schedule commands. An `ExecutorService` is like a scheduler of `Thread`s, ie a pool of `Thread`s which handles the life span of them and is responsible for example to create them and start them.

`Future` is an interface, an instance of which lets you monitor the execution time of an execution task (such as a `Thread`), ie check if complete, cancel it, etc... `Callable` is an interface, implementations of which are just generating/returning a result after a computation/method-call, or throw an `Exception` in case they are unable to produce the result. `Future` in our context will be returned by the scheduling commands of the `ExecutorService` to let us monitor the life span of the submitted `Callable`s...

The `Callable`s we are going to submit will simply return the result of `Scanner.nextLine` method call. By submitting a `Callable` to the scehduler we are getting back a `Future` which lets as wait for completion of the `Callable` for a given amount of time. To wait indefinitely for the completion of the `Callable` we use a [`get`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#get--) method. To wait for up to a specific timeout (which is what we are looking for) we use the other [`get`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#get-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-) method, supplying it with the amount of time we would like to wait.

There are several types of schedulers (ie `ExecutorService`s) we can create in Java 8 (which I am using, as you can tell from the links) and above, via the `Executors` helper class (we can create them by instantiating the corresponding classes also, but we'll use `Executors`' static methods for simplicity). I am not an expert on these, but generally speaking there is the *fixed thread pool* which lets at most the given number of `Thread`s to run at any given time, there is the *scheduled thread pool* which can execute `Thread`s at time-based rates and periods, there are *single thread* versions of them (ie same concept, only one `Thread` at a time), there is the *cached thread pool* which creates `Thread`s as needed and reuses existing finished ones, and finally there is the *work stealing pool* which has all its threads block/wait in parallel for work (I am not sure about the last one, but according to the docs can be useful when your tasks generate other tasks and so on).

Since we are submitting one `Callable` at a time (one `Scanner.nextLine` call at a time) we can utilize the single thread versions. And since we don't care about periodically executing the submitted `Callable` but instead we want to submit it after every time it finishes, then we are going to use the *fixed single thread pool* version.

You also don't need to have another thread started when the user's input is ready to be processed, but you can utilize the same thread that submitted the `Callable`s. This is the main thread in the following conceptual code:

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException;

public class Concept {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final LinkedList<String> q = new LinkedList<>(); //The collection to hold all user's input.
        final Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in); //The Scanner of the System.in input stream.
        final TimeUnit waitUnit = TimeUnit.SECONDS; //What unit of time should we use when waiting for input.
        final long waitAmount = 10; //How much time (in 'waitUnit' units) should we wait for.

        //An executor with a single (daemon) thread:
        final ExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor(r -> {
            final Thread t = new Thread(r);
            t.setDaemon(true);
            return t;
        });

        try {
            try {
                //Main loop for reading and waiting:
                for (String input = scheduler.submit(() -> scan.nextLine()).get(waitAmount, waitUnit);
                        !Objects.equals(input, "stop");
                        input = scheduler.submit(() -> scan.nextLine()).get(waitAmount, waitUnit))
                    q.add(input); //Add the user's last input to the collection.

                //If this is reached, then the user entered "stop" as input.
                System.out.println("Ended by user's input.");
            }
            catch (final TimeoutException tx) {
                //If this is reached, then the time timed out when waiting for user's input.
                System.out.println("Ended by timeout.");
            }
            finally {
                //Here you can "consume" however you like all the user's input from the collection:
                q.forEach(line -> System.out.println(line)); //I'm just printing all of it.
            }
        }
        catch (final InterruptedException | ExecutionException x) {
            x.printStackTrace(); //This is where you handle unexpected exceptions.
        }
        finally {
            //Whatever happened, don't forget to shutdown the ExecutorService:
            scheduler.shutdown();
        }
    }
}
```

Just give the word "stop" as input, and the main thread will proceed with the processing of the concatenated user's input. Or, alternatively, you can wait for 10 seconds, and a `TimeoutException` will be thrown, again proceeding with the processing of the concatenated user's input.

I am supplying the `Executors`' method call with a [`ThreadFactory`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadFactory.html). A `ThreadFactory` is simply an interface, implementations of which create `Thread`s for the given [`Runnable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html)s. `Runnable` is yet again an interface, which defines this time a single method (`run`) which executes a computation. This computation in our case is created internally in the `ExecutorService`, to store a reference of the result of the `Callable` we submitted, so as to make it available to the `get` methods of the returned `Future`, which will in turn make it available to the client's code. This `ThreadFactory`, I supply the `ExecutorService` with, is creating each `Thread` to be a *daemon* one. *Daemon* `Thread`s do not stop the program from terminating. When all non-*daemon* threads are done, the program is terminated, independently of whether some other (*daemon*) threads are still running.

As such, this comes down to the problem I faced while creating the code: if the user input is stopped from timeout instead of giving the word "stop" as input, that means that the `Callable` we submitted does not yet have completed. The `Callable` we submitted is waiting for input from the `System.in`. So that thread will run indefinitely, or until the user enters something. If the `Thread`s created were not *daemon* that would not let the program terminate. That's why I am making it *daemon*.

But what if, after the timeout, you wanted to keep reading from the `System.in` with (or without) the `Scanner` object created? Then you would have to maintain a reference first to the last `Future` returned by the last `ExecutorService.submit` method call.

So that is why, I have another version, which passes the scanning completely to another *wrapper* object called `TimedCallable` which you should use for every scanning. Even after timeout or finishing with a "stop" word, you should keep on using it to scan the `System.in`:

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException;

public class Main {

    public static class TimedCallable<V> implements Callable<V> {
        private final Callable<V> callable;
        private final ExecutorService scheduler;
        private Future<V> lastFuture;

        public TimedCallable(final Callable<V> callable) {
            this.callable = Objects.requireNonNull(callable);
            scheduler = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor(r -> {
                final Thread t = new Thread(r);
                t.setDaemon(true); //Needs to be a daemon in order to let the program end.
                return t;
            });
            lastFuture = null;
        }

        @Override
        public synchronized V call() throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
            if (lastFuture == null)
                try {
                    return callable.call();
                }
                catch (final Exception x) {
                    throw new ExecutionException(x);
                }
            final V v = lastFuture.get();
            lastFuture = null;
            return v;
        }

        public synchronized V call(final TimeUnit timeoutUnit,
                                   final long timeoutAmount) throws TimeoutException, InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
            if (lastFuture == null)
                lastFuture = scheduler.submit(callable);
            final V v = lastFuture.get(timeoutAmount, timeoutUnit); /*If it throws TimeoutException,
            then the 'lastFuture' property will not be nulled by the following statement:*/
            lastFuture = null;
            return v;
        }
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final LinkedList<String> q = new LinkedList<>(); //The collection to hold all user's input.
        final Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in); //The Scanner of the System.in input stream.
        final TimeUnit waitUnit = TimeUnit.SECONDS; //What unit of time should we use when waiting for input.
        final long waitAmount = 10; //How much time (in 'waitUnit' units) should we wait for.

        //Instantiate the scanner's timed-callable:
        final TimedCallable<String> scanNextLine = new TimedCallable<>(() -> scan.nextLine());

        try {
            try {
                //Main loop for reading and waiting:
                for (String input = scanNextLine.call(waitUnit, waitAmount); !Objects.equals(input, "stop"); input = scanNextLine.call(waitUnit, waitAmount))
                    q.add(input); //Add the user's last input to the collection.

                //If this is reached, then the user entered "stop" as input.
                System.out.println("Ended by user's input.");
            }
            catch (final TimeoutException tx) {
                //If this is reached, then the time timed out when waiting for user's input.
                System.out.println("Ended by timeout.");
            }
            finally {
                //Here you can "consume" however you like all the user's input from the collection:
                q.forEach(line -> System.out.println(line)); //I'm just printing all of it.

                //Keep on using the Scanner via the TimedCallable:
                System.out.println("Enter next line:");
                System.out.println(scanNextLine.call());
                System.out.println("Enter last line:");
                System.out.println(scanNextLine.call());
            }
        }
        catch (final InterruptedException | ExecutionException x) {
            x.printStackTrace(); //This is where you handle unexpected exceptions.
        }
    }
}
```

Final note: I made the assumption in both versions that the user might be interrupted from the timeout while still entering a sentence. For example if you set the timeout to be 1 second, then the user might not have enough time to enter what he wants, before the timeout expires and disrupts him. For more control over the input process, you would be better off creating a GUI and registering corresponding listener objects.