# Stop listening to user input

Tags: java, multithreading, java.util.scanner

Let's say I have a program like this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;


class State
{
    public volatile static boolean _userInput = false;
    public volatile static boolean _timeout = false;
}

public class Startup
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        
        class InputListener implements Runnable
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                System.out.println("Listening for user input...");
                Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
                String s = in.next();
                in.close();
                State._userInput = true;
                System.out.println("User input detected, listener thread shutting down...");
            }
        }
        
        class Timeout implements Runnable
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                try 
                {
                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                    State._timeout = true;
                } 
                catch (InterruptedException e) 
                {
                    System.out.println("Timeout thread interrupted");
                }
                
            }
        }
        
        Thread listener = new Thread(new InputListener());
        listener.start();
        Thread timeout = new Thread(new Timeout());
        timeout.start();
        
        while(true)
        {
            if(State._userInput)
            {
                System.out.println("Got user input");
                timeout.interrupt();
                break;
            }
            if(State._timeout)
            {
                System.out.println("Timeout");
                listener.interrupt();
                break;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Shutting down...");
    }

}
```

As you can see the program works as follows: Two threads are started: One of them times out after 2 seconds and the other one waits for user input. If any of the two threads succeed, the main thread closes the other thread and moves on. This is a simplified scenario from a larger project, where I basically wait for either a) user input or b) an external signal.

Interrupting the timeout thread with `Thread.interrupt()` works well, even though it is not really necessary because it would... well... just time out anyways. However, if a timeout happens first `Thread.interrupt` will ***not*** terminate the user input listener thread. This is a problem since even though the main thread is done and the program should terminate, it doesn't terminate because the input listener thread is still blocked at the `Scanner.next()` call and `Thread.interrupt()` does nothing. I have tried several things now and it seems like it is `impossible` to get rid of this thread without the user providing at least one more line inside the console, which I'd like to prevent to be necessary. Is there any way to solve this?

I am making a console application, so I can't just get the input from somewhere else.

Comment: Can't you use `System.exit(0);` to terminate the program when timed-out? Is the sequence of events (ie user input or timeout) repeated throughout the up time, or is it just happening only once?

Comment: @JanezKuhar The workaround in the question you linked works for me. Thanks.

Comment: By the way, there is [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60718858/how-would-one-time-out-a-thread-if-there-is-no-input-on-system-in-in-the-last-15) relating to your question, so I am linking it. It might as well be a duplicate because of the great similarity. Check out the `TimedCallable` class of my answer there.